# regex expression with preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have to replace some characters in a large string based on some rule:

I'll try to give a couple of examples hoping it'll make it more clear than actually trying to explain the rule:

- `{{ @ text @@ text }}` should be `{{ @ text # text}}`
- `@@ text {{ text 123 @ te@@xt @@ text 34@}}` should be `@@ text {{ text 123 @ te#xt # text 34@}}` (if `@@` is not between `{{` and `}}` it should get ignored; also, all `@@`s between `{{` and `}}` should get replaced)

I tried `$text = preg_replace("/({{.*)[@]{2}(.*}})/U", '\\1#\\2', $text);` but with no success.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php), "{" and "}" are reserved characters used for the start/end min/max quantifier. For this reason, you should backslash these characters in your pattern:

```
$text = preg_replace("/(\{\{.*)[@]{2}(.*\}\})/U", '\\1#\\2', $text);
```

This will replace only one occurrence so you have to put your code in a loop like this:

```
$text = '@@ text {{ text 123 @ te@@xt @@ text 34@}}';
do
{
    $textBefore = $text;
    $text = preg_replace("/(\{\{.*)[@]{2}(.*\}\})/U", '\\1#\\2', $text);
} while($textBefore != $text);
```

Comment: thanks! but isn't there a flag I can use? or some other method to avoid putting it in a cycle?

Comment: Good question @SorinButurugeanu. As far as I know, no.